# xUnit: Passing object containing reference to static fields as theory

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I'm going to test function returning array of von Neumann neighbours of cell in 2D Array.
Cells contains data about simulation.

To conduct test I'm setting new Cell[,] and populate with Cell instances.
The test should check if neighbours returned by function is this same instances as expected and in this same order in array.

```
public class VonNeumanNeighbourhoodTest
{
    private static Cell a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i ;    
    private static Cell[,] space;

    public VonNeumanNeighborhoodTest() {
        a = new Cell{ GrainMembership = new Grain(0, Color.Red) };
        b = new Cell{ GrainMembership = new Grain(1, Color.Green) };
        // And so on 
        i = new Cell{ GrainMembership = new Grain(8, Color.Azure) };

        space = new Cell[3, 3]
            {
                { a, b, c },
                { d, e, f },
                { g, h, i }
        };
    }
```

The problem occures in test method. `Cell[] expected` always contains {null, null, null, null} in debug instead of eg.{b, f, h, d} reference.

```
    [Theory]
    [ClassData(typeof(AbsorbingTestData))]
    public void AbsorbingTest(int x, int y, Cell[] expected)
    {
        var neighbours = VonNeumanNeighbourhood.Neighbours(space , x, y, AbsorbingBoundary.BoundaryCondition);
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
                Assert.Same(neighbours[i], expected[i]);//Checking if neighbours and expected are this same instances
            }
        }

    }
private class AbsorbingTestData : IEnumerable<object[]>
        {   
            public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
            {
                yield return new object[] { 1, 1, new Cell[]{b, f, h, d} }; //e - center
                yield return new object[] { 0, 0, new Cell[]{null, b, d, null} }; //a
                //More cases
            }

            IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
            }

    }
```

I was trying similar code with [MemberData] attribute but with this same results.

Comment: worth noting, the class is spelled with 'u' while the constructor is spelled without. In addition, how do you initialize static properties in a class constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into an order-of-initialization issue. The `Cell` instances (`private static Cell a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;`) are static, but are initialized by an instance constructor. There's no guarantee that the constructor will run before xUnit enumerates the test cases.

Try replacing the instance constructor (`public VonNeumanNeighborhoodTest()`) with a static initializer (`static VonNeumanNeighborhoodTest()`). Be careful, though--with a static initializer, the values won't get re-set between tests. You might be better off looking for  a way to eliminate the use of `static` entirely.

Comment: After setting VonNeumanNeighborhoodTest() as static and throwing out constructor it seems to work. In fact cells won't be changed during testing so I don't need to reset them in constructor. 

I've tried to set the breakpoint in AbsorbingTestData.GetEnumerator() and constructor - only code that was invoked was constructor.